# Can I use RDP while still having the computer logged in?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, remote-access

Whenver I use remote desktop connection on my other computer, it logs that computer out so that I can control it. Is it possible to use remote desktop connection while still having the computer that is being controlled stay logged on?

Comment: Are you asking about RDP'ing into the _same_ account as locally, or into a different one?

Answer (score 2):

This is a deliberate limitation in the desktop versions of Windows.  It's so that you don't go using a workstation as a terminal server without paying for it.

Also FYI, Windows 7 does not log your account out on remote access. It just locks it.  Windows 7 fully supports multiple people logged in.  It just won't allow them to be using the computer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There are some 3rd Party Methods that could help you with having multiple sessions to the same computer.

Please remember that these are not supported by Microsoft and there's a possibility that you could be in violation of your TOS (Terms of Service) meaning your license could be blacklisted.

[Enable Multiple User Access/Concurrent User Sessions For Remote Desktop on Windows 7](http://www.blogsdna.com/2336/enable-multiple-user-accessconcurrent-user-sessions-for-remote-desktop-on-windows-7.htm)

[How To Allow Multiple Remote Desktop Connections on Vista](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remote-desktop-concurrent-sessions-for-windows-vista/)

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try it for windows 7 and hope it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Do upvote & select my answer if you think it helped resolve your issue :)

Comment: First link is dead.